# Quirkiness with jQuery mouseenter - mouseleave

Tags: jquery, hover, nested, mouseevent, accordion

I am trying to animate an element when the cursor enters its parent element and reverse that animation reliably when the mouse exits the element - for multiple levels of nested elements. I can do it clunkily with CSS (transitions not an option) but want to use jQuery to sexy it up ;)

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is this type of [accordion menu](http://jsfiddle.net/wuUD9/4/) but, as I say, with jQuery.

So far I have [tried using mouseenter and mouseleave](http://jsfiddle.net/Rce8A/1/) for the same example but can't seem to get it to work after the first expand and contract.

How can I reliably and elegantly bind this hide/show animation to a mouseenter/mouseleave or something similar in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems work

http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/Rce8A/2/

```
$(function(){
  //bind event
  $("li.level1").mouseenter(   
    function(){
       // make sure the item would diplay
       $(this).find("ul:first").find("li.level2").show(); 
       // do "show" 
       $(this).find("ul:first").show(500);       
    });

  $("li.level1").mouseleave(
      function() {
        // do "hide" 
        $(this).find(":parent").hide(500);
      }
  );
});
```

Comment: By the way, I choose jquery 1.8 (in left column)

Comment: Hmmm yes it does seem to work but looks hacky. Can you explain why it works?

Comment: The most important is to bind event

Comment: nothing ....., you just forgot to choose jquery version in http://jsfiddle.net/Rce8A/1/

However, in your code, there is a tiny bug. 
you have to add 
$(this).find("ul:first").find("li.level2").show(); 
to make item display collectly

Comment: I know the jQuery lib wasnt the issue. But looking at your solution it looks like you came by it by accident... Can you explain why you have written it like that and not like: `$(this).find("ul:first, ul:first > li").show(500)` for instance which is leaner and more efficient??

Comment: Sorry. I didn't measure the performance before....
I used to write it like: $("ul:first, ul:first > li", this).show(500);
It's just my coding style...